# My daughter has an expired Australian passport can she use her british passport to enter Australia. Will immigration allow this?

Tags: passports, australian-citizens

My husband and three children are Australian, my youngest is 7 and her Australian passport has expired.

Will she be able to travel back to Australia on her British passport and just prove she is Australian when we arrive?